# Pasar una variable ya almacenada, a otra pagina en el mismo sitio web en asp.net

Tags: asp.net, asp, variables

Tengo una variable que recibo de una pagina login.aspx, en la pagina login consulto un webservice que me devuelve un token, dicho token lo envió a una masterpage, en donde se valida, si es valido carga la máster page si no redirecciona al login, esta parte ya se hace, el problema es cuando quiero seguir navegando en el dentro del sitio cada que doy click en un enlace me vuelve a redirecciona al login, supongo que por que no envió la variable,¿Como hacer para que traer esa variable en todo el sitio?

Comment: ¡Bienvenido a SOes!, favor de revisar [cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) para que puedas [editar](http://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/52832/edit) tu pregunta.

Comment: Hola Francisco, bienvenido a [es.so], una pregunta ¿Qué lenguaje de programación utilizas?

Comment: Hola buen día, gracias, mira utilizo c#, quiero traer esa variable en otras paginas y que no me redireccione a mi login.

Comment: @FranciscoGuillermoHerreraGa pon el codigo para revisarlo. Pero en vez de variable crea una Variable de Sesión.